# Determine day based on number

Tags: algorithm

I just want to ask if how do you determine

```
Enter a number: 14
Then the date to day is Sunday.
```

the above demonstration is  from 1-7=monday-sunday then if the value is 8 then its monday again...but how could I determine it?using loops and modulo?...

I appreciate any comments for helping me...

any language are ok, I just want to know the algorithm with it...

Comment: It sounds like you are aware of modulo, so have you tried it yet?

Comment: this is not a home work guys its just a manipulation to my website, like I want to know the current date but I store it all to decimal, so how could I divide it to 7 then get its remaining value?...

Answer (score 2):

You can just use module

Module got to 0 so it would be something like

```
<?php
    $value = 13;
    $daynames = array("mon", "tues", "wed", "thur", "fri", "sat", "sun");

    // The + 1 is because % is 0, and you want 1-7
    echo (($value % 7) + 1) .  "day of the week";
    echo "the day is " . $daynames[($value % 7)];
?>
```

Example: http://codepad.org/wbGuMI06

Answer (score 1):

If you have a switch/case or if/else for the seven days you can use modulo 7 to get the input into the desired range of 7 days.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a switch statement and modulo arithmetic to do this.

The first step to learning computer science is to learn that numbers don't usually start at 1. They start at 0. Getting this idea down will help you tremendously in the future!

```
// accept numbers 0-6. If 7 were to get put in, it would end up being 0 since 7 % 7 = 0.

switch(num % 7) {
case 0: return "Sunday";
case 1: return "Monday";
case 2: return "Tuesday";
/// rest here...
default: throw new IllegalArgumentException();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking the number modulo 7 would seem like the obvious possibility.

Answer (score 1):

```
string day;
int inputNumber;

if(inputNumber%7 == 0)
  day = "monday";  // or sunday if you prefer :p
else if(inputNumber%7 == 1)
  day = tuesday
...
...
...
```

Comment: so you'll do a different if statement for each day?

Answer (score 1):

In C++, `int day = (i-1) % 7;` will give you a zero-based offset.  Here's sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    static const std::string days [] = 
    {
        "Sunday",
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday",
        "Saturday"
    };

    static const size_t num_days = sizeof(days)/sizeof(days[0]);

    for( int i = 1; i <= 31; ++i )
    {
        int day = (i-1) % 7;
        cout << day << " = " << days[day] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get modulo 7 of the int value thats passed in and make a switch statement for it.

```
switch:
   case 1:
    Sunday
   case 2:
    Monday 

    // and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

```
datArr= new Array ('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue',Wen', 'Thu, 'Fri', 'Sat');
day =datArr[(daynum%7)];
```

If Sunday gets treated as day zero there is no need to subtract 1 after the modulo. Of course most of the solutions will fail with zero dive if an actual value of zero is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestMain {
    private static final String[] DAYS = new String[] { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thusday", "Friday", "Saturday" };

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");

        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int n = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Then the date to day is " + DAYS[n % 7]);
    }
}
```